# Multi threading error segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to multiply two matrices using multi threading. Here I compile the program using gcc in linux and run by inputting number of threads.

```
gcc multiThread.c -o test -lpthread
./test 4
```

Here I run the multiplication for matrices of N*N where N starting from 10 to 1000 with intervals of 10 and calculate the execution time tor each iteration. When I run the program it gives a segmentation fault. Please help.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int SIZE = 10;   // Size by SIZE matrices
int num_thrd;   // number of threads

int A[2000][2000], B[2000][2000], C[2000][2000];

// initialize a matrix
void init_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE])
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
      m[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
}

// thread function: taking "slice" as its argument
void* multiply(void* slice)
{
  int s = (int)slice;   // retrive the slice info
  int from = (s * SIZE)/num_thrd; // note that this 'slicing' works fine
  int to = ((s+1) * SIZE)/num_thrd; // even if SIZE is not divisible by num_thrd
  int i,j,k;

  printf("computing slice %d (from row %d to %d)\n", s, from, to-1);
  for (i = from; i < to; i++)
  {  
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
      C[i][j] = 0;
      for ( k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
    C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }
  }
  printf("finished slice %d\n", s);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE *outFile;
  outFile = fopen("Algorithm3_Times.txt", "r");
  pthread_t* thread;  // pointer to a group of threads
for(int ini=0; ini<100; ini++)
{


  int i;

  if (argc!=2)
  {
    printf("Usage: %s number_of_threads\n",argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
  }

  num_thrd = atoi(argv[1]);
  init_matrix(A);
  init_matrix(B);
  clock_t start = clock();
  thread = (pthread_t*) malloc(num_thrd*sizeof(pthread_t));
  // this for loop not entered if threadd number is specified as 1
  for (i = 1; i < num_thrd; i++)
  {
    // creates each thread working on its own slice of i
    if (pthread_create (&thread[i], NULL, multiply, (void*)i) != 0 )
    {
      perror("Can't create thread");
      free(thread);
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  // main thread works on slice 0
  // so everybody is busy
  // main thread does everything if threadd number is specified as 1
  multiply(0);

  // main thead waiting for other thread to complete
  for (i = 1; i < num_thrd; i++)
    pthread_join (thread[i], NULL);

  clock_t end = clock();

  float time = (end - start)*1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  fprintf(outFile,"time taken for Multiplication using %d", num_thrd);
  fprintf(outFile," threads =  %f", time);
  fprintf(outFile," milliseconds \n");
  if (thread != NULL)
  {
      free(thread);
      thread = NULL;
  }
  SIZE += 10;

 }

  printf("calculation completed.\n\n");
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you want to do anything remotely complex with C, you really _need_ to start using a debugger.  I really kicked myself when I finally realized how much of my life I had wasted because I didn't learn `gdb` soon enough.  don't make the same mistake I did!  Use a debugger!

Comment: Why did you tag C++?

Comment: This is not the main problem, but the calls `init_matrix(A);` and `init_matrix(B);` are not initializing the parts of the array that you think they are. Did you get a compiler warning about incompatible pointer types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is a hard language, especially because runtime errors by default include no useful debugging information.  This is where a debugger comes in.

How I debugged this with docker/alpine:

1. put the code into `~/gcc/t.c` for sharing to my docker
2. `docker run --rm -it -v`ls -d ~`/gcc:/code alpine`
3. `apk add build-base gdb musl-dbg` to install gcc & friends, gdb, and musl-dbg which I'll need to debug the segfault in the standard library.
4. `cd /code`
5. `gcc -g t.c -o t`
6. `gdb t`

Now here's my debugger session:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.1

[ ... preamble removed for brevity ... ]

Reading symbols from t...done.
(gdb) run 1
Starting program: /code/t 1
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted
computing slice 0 (from row 0 to 9)
finished slice 0

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
vfprintf (f=0x0, fmt=0x560896553020 "time taken for Multiplication using %d",
    ap=ap@entry=0x7ffcb18b29f8) at src/stdio/vfprintf.c:671
671 src/stdio/vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  vfprintf (f=0x0,
    fmt=0x560896553020 "time taken for Multiplication using %d",
    ap=ap@entry=0x7ffcb18b29f8) at src/stdio/vfprintf.c:671
#1  0x00007fa6ef0c056f in fprintf (f=<optimized out>, fmt=<optimized out>)
    at src/stdio/fprintf.c:9
#2  0x0000560896552ee2 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7ffcb18b2b68) at t.c:87
```

Great, now we have a line number to go see.  Line 87 is this line:

```
fprintf(outFile,"time taken for Multiplication using %d", num_thrd);
```

We can take a look at the line, do a little thinking, and eventually come to look at the definition of `outFile`:

```
outFile = fopen("Algorithm3_Times.txt", "r");
```

Ah ha!  We expect to write to outFile, but we opened it for reading!   I change to opening for writing:

```
  outFile = fopen("Algorithm3_Times.txt", "w");
```

And your program runs (note below I only show the first 10 lines)

```
/code # ./t 10  |head
computing slice 1 (from row 1 to 1)
finished slice 1
computing slice 2 (from row 2 to 2)
computing slice 3 (from row 3 to 3)
finished slice 3
finished slice 2
computing slice 4 (from row 4 to 4)
finished slice 4
computing slice 5 (from row 5 to 5)
finished slice 5
```

Now that you've gotten introduced to `gdb`, you can start working on putting in gdb `break` statements at particular lines and work through any remaining bugs.  My program didn't seem to ever finish but I didn't give it very much time.